# How to use 'sparklyr::replace.na()' for replacing NaN on one column?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am using sparklyr for interact with spark. I am trying to replace NaN values in just one column.

Is it possible to use the sparklyr function `replace.na()` but only apply it to one column? I checked the documentation but it did not help me.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699198/how-to-use-spark-apply-to-change-nan-values) is similar, but the answer changes all the NaN values within the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you actually have to specify the column when using `sparklyr::na.replace()`. See https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/127#issuecomment-236318033.

Example:

```
temp <- tibble(
  a = c(1, 2, NA),
  b = c("A", NA, "B")
)

temp_spark <- sdf_copy_to(sc, temp, "temp_spark")

temp_spark %>%
  na.replace()
#  a  | b
#  1  | A
#  2  | NA
# NaN | B

temp_spark %>%
  na.replace(a = 0)
# a | b
# 1 | A
# 2 | NA
# 0 | B
```